# Infinite scroll with Bootstrap in angular problem

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem. I'm trying to implement a Infinite scroll in my Angular project. The scroll works fine, but I can't bind the data inside a row to display the data in a grid.

This is my code:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport *ngIf="!buscar" style="height: 100vh" itemSize="50" >
<ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let venue of venues">
  <div class=" col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card" [routerLink]="['/salas/details/', venue.id]">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid venue-img animated fadeIn slow" onError="this.src='../../../assets/img/brand/giramos-logo.gif';" src="{{venue.img}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{venue.nombre}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{venue.ciudad}} / {{venue.distrito}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-container> </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

If I try to put the row class in the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` or in the `ng-container` all crash. So I don't put the row class and works fine, but the result is this:

[The items are one per row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZCIv.jpg)

If I inspect the page and I edit the HTML adding the row class I can obtain the desired result:

[The desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeDUb.jpg)

How can I obtain this result? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://netbasal.com/a-taste-of-angular-material-virtual-scroll-f173c5c70a1

Answer (score 0):

I newer version of angular we found fine solution using angular cdk **(@angular/cdk. (v7.0.0-beta.0))**.

https://netbasal.com/a-taste-of-angular-material-virtual-scroll-f173c5c70a1

I think it's save your time.